# What was Syrian side of the story for the 1989 shooting of a Turkish aircraft?

Tags: aircraft, turkey, border, syria

Wikipedia briefly [notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syria%E2%80%93Turkey_relations):

> In October 1989, 2 Syrian Mig-21's flew 12 miles (19 km) into Turkish airspace where they shot down a Turkish aircraft.

Most of the articles linked there are dead links by now, but one in LA Times says

> Two Syrian MIG-21 jets intruded 12 miles into Turkish airspace and shot down a plane conducting a land survey, killing all five people on board, the Turkish Foreign Ministry said. Two fliers, a surveyor, a photographer and an official aboard the twin-propeller plane were killed, a spokesman said. In Damascus, **Syria ordered an inquiry into the incident** and offered condolences to the Turkish government.

I found a longer (AP) [piece](https://apnews.com/article/a20d8ae71a4451c05176829be10e667b) in the meantime, which gives much detail from the Turkish side, but still it says little if anything of what Syria said either then or in the aftermath, other than promising to investigate. (There is actually a claim in the latter story that one Syrian official supposedly promised that the pilots would be severely punished, however this was reported by a Turkish source, rather than coming directly from the Syrians.)

So, what did the Syrian inquiry find?

Comment: Syria at the time was one of the [worst despotisms in the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presidency_of_Hafez_al-Assad). I wouldn't consider it likely an inquiry actually happened just on their say-so.